# What is "-->" operator in prolog?

Tags: prolog

My code is in Prolog:

```
act( [left, Susan, Bahman, Hosein, left, T1],
     (Ahmad)left --> (Ahmad)right,
     [right, Susan, Bahman, Hosein, right, T2]) :-
   T2 is T1 + 1.
```

What is `-->` ?

Comment: it's a splitting head from tale.

Comment: please explain more!!!!

Comment: [http://www.logic.at/prolog/dcg.html](http://www.logic.at/prolog/dcg.html)
,
[http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_1.html](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_1.html) and [http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse29](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-->` is a built-in infix operator, used for prolog's built-in DCG support (`DCG` = *Definite Clause Grammar*). It is used like this:

```
sentence    --> noun_phrase , verb_phrase .
noun_phrase --> det , noun .
verb_phrase --> verb , noun_phrase .

det  --> [the] .
det  --> [a]   .

noun --> [cat] .
noun --> [bat]  .

verb --> [tickles] .
verb --> [eats]    .
```

Which is simply a convenient way (*syntactic sugar*) for

```
sentence(    S1,S3 ) :- noun_phrase(S1,S2) , verb_phrase(S2,S3) .
noun_phrase( S1,S3 ) :- det(S1,S2) , noun(S2,S3) .
verb_phrase( S1,S3 ) :- verb(S1,S2) , noun_phrase(S2,S3) .

det(  [the|X]  , X) .
det(  [a|X]    , X) .

noun( [cat|X]  , X) .
noun( [bat|X]  , X) .

verb( [tickles|X] , X ) .
verb( [eats|X]    , X ) .
```

And gives you a parser for a small set of sentences.

None of that applies in your case — the expression `X --> Y` is just infix notation for the structure `'-->'(X,Y)`.

Your example:

```
act( [left, Susan, Bahman, Hosein, left, T1],
     (Ahmad) left --> (Ahmad) right ,
     [right, Susan, Bahman, Hosein, right, T2]
) :-
   T2 is T1 + 1
.
```

isn't even valid Prolog, unless you've got `left` and `right` defined as suffix operators. In which case, it is exactly equivalent to:

```
act( [ left , Susan , Bahman , Hosein , left , T1 ] ,
     left(Ahmad) --> right(Ahmad) ,
     [ right , Susan , Bahman , Hosein , right , T2 ]
) :-
   T2 is T1 + 1
.
```

And since your names ( `Susan`, `Bahman`, `Hosein` and `Ahmad` ) all start with an upper-case letter, they are *variables* rather than *atoms* or *strings*, making the entire expression the equivalent of

```
act( [left,S,B,H,left,T1] , left(A) --> right(A) , [right,S,B,H,right,T2] ) :-
   T2 is T1 + 1 .
```

All it does is match the three arguments and enforce the constraint that the last element of the right list, `T2` is 1 more than than the value of the last element in the left list, `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has two parts: what does `-->` do in this example, and what it does in general.

In the given example it does nothing. Prolog allows for operators to act as functor. Functors are Prolog's built-in recursive data structures. For example `foo(bar, baz)` in Prolog is roughly equivalent to an object named `foo` with its first field set to `bar` and the second to `baz` in some other language. `bar --> baz` is the same as `-->(bar, baz)` which is the same as the previous, just with `-->` as the functor's name.

Some Prolog interpreters, e.g. SWI-Prolog, interpret rules whose head ends with `-->` instead of `:-` as grammar rules. See [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Definite_Clause_Grammars).

It is not the case in your example since the `act` rule head ends with `:-`.

As it seems, the `act` predicate expects invocation such as `act(List1,  L-->R, List2)`. I can't understand why from your brief code.